# TFDMemTable and ListView

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe8

I created a firemonkey (XE8) application. 
My app reads data from XML file and populate a memTable from this. The memTable is binding a ´ListView´.

All works fine, but this process is very slow. I try using a `progressbar`, but when run the `repeat` loop, "freezes the application" and back to work when the `ListView` is completely filled.

How I can fix this?

Code:

```
procedure TForm2.layoutCatalogoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
Node: IXMLNode;
auxValor :Double;
begin
Label2.Visible := True;

mmtListaProdutos.Close;
mmtListaProdutos.CreateDataSet;
mmtListaProdutos.Open;

XMLDocument1.FileName := 'C:\dados\xml.xml';
XMLDocument1.Active := true;

Node := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('produto');
Node.ChildNodes.First;

ProgressBar1.Max := node.ChildNodes.Count;
ProgressBar1.Value := 0;

repeat

  ProgressBar1.Value := ProgressBar1.Value + 1;
  auxValor := StrToFloat(Node.ChildNodes['valor_preco_a'].Text);

  mmtListaProdutos.Append;
  mmtListaProdutoscodigo.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['codigo'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosdescricao.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['descricao'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosreferencia.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['referencia'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutoscodigo_EAN.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['codigo_EAN'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosgrupo.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['grupo'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosfornecedor.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['fornecedor'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosmarca.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['marca'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosunidade.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['unidade'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosvalidade.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['validade'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosvalor_preco_a.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['valor_preco_a'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosvalor_preco_b.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['valor_preco_b'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosaltura.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['altura'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutoscomprimento.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['comprimento'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutoslargura.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['largura'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutoscodDesc.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['codigo'].Text + ' | ' + Node.ChildNodes['descricao'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosvalorUnd.AsString := 'R$ ' + FormatFloat('#.00', auxValor) + ' / ' + Node.ChildNodes['unidade'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutosmarcaFornec.AsString := Node.ChildNodes['marca'].Text;
  mmtListaProdutos.Post;

  Node := Node.NextSibling;

until Node = nil;
mmtListaProdutos.First;

pnlListaProdutos.Visible := True;
pnlPrincipal.Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: Not related to the slowness, but you should check for `Node = nil` before the `Repeat` loop, in case there are no children

Answer (score 1):

Live Binding is not quick, especially when a multi-row GUI component like a `listview` is involved. And loading the data into the `dataset` via the `listview` is a particularly inefficient way of doing it.

What I'd try is disconnecting the bindings (in code) from the `FDMemTable`, loading the data directly into the `FDMemTable`, rather than into the listview, and then re-connecting the bindings to the `FDMemTable`.